# Удаление букв из введённой строки

Tags: c++

Нужно ввести строку, затем удалить из неё все буквы А и О.
Пример кода:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char  str[30];

    int  n=26;

    char  s='a';
    for (int i=0; i<n;  i++,  s++)
        str[i]=s;
    str[n]='\0';
    //вывод массива
    cout <<str<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну так он уже и так выглядит **так**... :)

Comment: Ну и? Где, спрашивается, ВАШИ попытки решить задачу? решать её ВМЕСТО Вас тут никто не будет - тут не бюро добрых услуг.

Comment: @Андрей , даже если вы удалили код - это не сделало вопрос лучше. Скорее наоборот, вы убрали свою попытку решения. Попробуйте улучшить вопрос, добавив в него информацию о том, что именно у вас не получается, опираясь на представленный код.

Comment: Немного вам помог, отредактировав вопрос, дальше дело за вами. На всякий случай напоминаю - просто решать за вас тут врятли кто-то будет.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str[30];    
    int n=26, c=0;

    for (int i=(int)'a'; i<((int)'a'+n); i++) 
    {
        cout << (char)i;        
        if (i!='a' && i!='o') str[c++]= i;
    }
        
    str[c]='\0';
    //вывод массива
    cout << endl << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Результат:
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
bcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyz

Answer (score -1):

`std::find()`  и  `std::erase()` вам в помощь

Comment: С прологом: _вам в помощь_, оформляйте комментарием, а не ответом.